# Error:Error: Expected resource of type drawable [ResourceType]

Tags: android

The project works good, but when I try to generate signed APK it shows me an error: Error: Expected resource of type drawable [ResourceType] in MainActivity:

```
public void buttonTapped(View view) {
    int id= view.getId();
    String ourId="";
    ourId=view.getResources().getResourceEntryName(id);
    int resourceImId = getResources().getIdentifier(ourId, "drawable", getPackageName());
    im.setImageResource(resourceImId);
    int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier(ourId, "raw", getPackageName());
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, resourceId); mp.start();
}
```

App shows an image and plays sound when you click the button. Problem is why all is ok  in case of sounds but there is an error here:

```
   int resourceImId = getResources().getIdentifier(ourId, "drawable", getPackageName());
   im.setImageResource(resourceImId);
```

I appreciate any help

Comment: Do you use Butterknife in your project ?

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is not error. It is just lint check warning. If everything works fine, you can ignore the error by adding this to your gradle file:

```
android { 
       lintOptions{
             disable "ResourceType"
       }
}
```

The reason of this error can be you have drawable outside `drawable` folder.